# Change colour of liquid in GIMP

Tags: gimp

Just wondering if it is possible to change the colour of a liquid in GIMP?

I have followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pn7rrMZ6TCA

While it teaches us how to set a transparent layer, when I add a colour over the liquid, the colour doesn't change exactly to the one I want (since it is layered over the original colour of the liquid and shows the blended of the two).

Thanks.

Comment: Try the `Color` blend mode instead of `Overlay`. The problem with these tutorials is that they start with an image on which the tutorial works well, and a matte middle-grey car makes it very easy. Another method would be to just use [`Colors>Map>Rotate colors`](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-filter-color-rotate.html) on the image. There is no absolute answer, it all depends on the color you start with and the color you want to obtain so posting a an image extract would help.

Comment: @xenoid thank you for the reply. May I know where to find `Color`? I only see `Color Erase` (https://i.imgur.com/XC95mDj.png).

Comment: Ah, yes, in 2.10 it's either `HSL Color` or `LCh color` (both at the bottom of the list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use the method employed in that tutorial.

Instead duplicate the background layer, select the top layer, and do a Hue-Saturation adjustment, moving the sliders until the liquid turns the colour you want. This will of course change the colour of the whole image.  But then you can add a black filled layer mask, select the Layer mask by clicking on it, and with the foreground colour set to white, use the Paint Brush tool to paint only where you want the colour revealed. If you make a mistake you can switch the foreground colour to black, and paint over the areas you messed up to erase the colour.

Example

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This works great!